# Looping through collections doesn't work

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm making a page where I need to compare an input ( in a form ) to the titles of my existing collections.

Right now I'm trying to loop like this:

```
div class="test">
    {{% for collection in collections %}}
        {{collection.title}}
    {{% endfor %}}
  </div>
```

I've seen this code in another snippet ('collection-listing.liquid') so I assumet it might be correct.

Could anyone tell me why it's not working? I'm new at this so I still don't fully understand Shopify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from your snippet, try to fix the malformed HTML 
tag first.

Next, there is an error in the `for` loop.
Instead of

`{{% for .... %}} ... {{% endfor %}}`

it's

`{% for ... %} ... {% endfor %}`

```
   <div class="test">
        {% for collection in collections %}
            {{collection.title}}
        {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

Comment: Yeah... Noticed 5 mins ago ! Thanks :D